# How to send or receive xml file in Flutter?

Tags: xml, https, flutter

I can send and receive JSON, string data with Flutter. But I cannot find any information how to send and receive xml file with Flutter.

I am looking good documentation and basic hands-on-example. Any help please?

Comment: There is an xml package on pub.dartlang.org that allows to convert between string and XML

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks for info, but that is not dart 2 compatible

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml#-changelog-tab- , https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml/blob/master/pubspec.yaml#L9 indicates otherwise

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks. I see that one as well but I am trying to avoid when package analyzed score less than 80. If this is the best option than I will try to help them to get the analyzed score over 80. Seems they get less score due to less detail example of plugin.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728107/how-to-post-send-xml-data-instead-of-json-in-rest-api-flutter/62740541#62740541)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @GünterZöchbauer. I mange to build xml in Flutter and be able to post and get the response. Here is the code:

**DEPENDENCIES:**

```
// Add pubspec.yaml:   xml: "^3.2.1"
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
import 'dart:io';
```

**BUILD XML:**

```
// TODO: BUILD XML FILE
Future<HttpClientResponse> _sendOTP() async {
  var builder = new xml.XmlBuilder();
  builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-9"');
  builder.element('MainmsgBody', nest: () {
    builder.element('UserName', nest: “xxxxxxxx”);
    builder.element('PassWord', nest: “yyyyyyyy”);
    builder.element('Action', nest: 5);
    builder.element('Mesgbody', nest: “I am Fluttering with Dart”);
    builder.element('Numbers', nest: 5);
  });
  var bookshelfXml = builder.build();
  String _uriMsj = bookshelfXml.toString();
  print("_uriMsj: $_uriMsj");

  String _uri = "https://*******.******.com/http****”;
  var _responseOtp = postOTP(_uri, _uriMsj);
  print("_responseOtp: $_responseOtp");
}


**POST XML:**
 // TODO: POST XML FILE
Future<String> postOTP(String _uri, String _message) async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(_uri));
  request.write(_message);
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  StringBuffer _buffer = new StringBuffer();
  await for(String a in await response.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
    _buffer.write(a);
  }
  print("_buffer.toString: ${_buffer.toString()}");
  return _buffer.toString();
}
```